# Complex manifolds as algebro-geometric objects

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

A result of Artin states that analytification of proper algebraic spaces over
$\mathbb{C}$ defines an an equivalence of the category of proper algebraic spaces with the category of Moishezon spaces. Is there some way to make sense algebro-geometrically of compact complex-analytic spaces of lower algebraic dimension?

Comment: For the maximal meromorphic quotient $f:X\to Y$ with $Y$ algebraic, presumably you can think of $X$ as the pullback over $Y$ of the tautological family of complex analytic spaces for the natural meromorphic map from $Y$ to the Douady space of the fibers of $f$.